# Converting loop in CLI to Dialog box

Tags: c++, user-interface, command-line-interface, gtkmm

I'm working on converting a c++ OO program from Command Line Interface to Graphical User Interface by using dialog boxes. Everything is working fine except when I try to convert a loop to dialog box. The dialog box should print out all 4 elements in the following enum,

```
enum Genre {fiction, nonfiction, selfhelp, performance};
const vector<string> genres = {"fiction", "nonfiction", "self help", "performance"};
```

followed by an input option for the user. Instead, it prints out the elements one by one, in the their own dialog boxes.How do I get it to print all 4 at the same time? This is the code for the dialog box:

```
for (int i = 0; i < genres.size(); ++i)
    gen=Dialogs::input(genres[i],input);
```